# How to create search functionality in site.com site?

Tags: site.com

I want to create search functionality in site.com site which i created. In that, based on search keyword i want to display related content from that site.I have a website which has various kind of data, what i want to do is after entering a a word, my site should display the page names which contain that word.I basically have no idea of whether we can do that in site.com or not. so just wanted to ask that what i should do to implement that functionality?

Comment: Hi Koustubh, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful. As an example, knowing more about the kind of content you want to add search capabilities for would be helpful.

Comment: Hello  crmprogdev , thanks for your suggestion about reading those articles. I edited my question as you suggested, but problem with my question is I wanted to know whether or not this search functionality can be implemented in site.com. So i will appreciate anything which will help me implementing that functionality.Thanks and i think you should consider this question for reopening.

Comment: What you're asking about would seem to me to require a SOSL query. Have nominated for reopening. Suggest you investigate dynamic SOSL query controllers "with sharing" on the objects you wish to expose. Please edit your question to include a general description of custom objects/content you want to expose if you want a useful response and the votes from others to get this reopened.

Comment: Basically SOQL wont help because i dont want to search any records(fields,objects) within the salesforce. I just want to search within the static content of the site.com itself.Anyways, thanks for the reply and suggestions.

Comment: You want to search the content of the static pages? If so, sounds like you want to implement a link to a Google Search engine of some kind and allow them to "crawl" at least parts of your site. You'd only want to do that if your site is open to the public as guest users. Not the thing to do for a Secure/Private Site. To enable specific pages for crawling by Google with robots.txt see https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000159800&language=en_US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site.com doesn't seem to have a search feature.

That being said, you can see what this person suggests https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AK9IAM or try indexing it with google search.